# MSExchangeMailSubmission service is not listed or running; sent mail not working

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

I am running a new Exchange 2007 SP1 system.  I moved the mailboxes from the old Exchange 2003 server, and incoming mail is working.

But outgoing mail is not working at all; even inside my domain.

Lots of debugging and searching lead me to believe that the problem is that the "Microsoft Exchange Mail Submission Service" (AKA MSExchangeMailSubmission) is not running.

In fact, it's not even listed in the Services list.

This document (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998342.aspx) says that this service is installed by the Mailbox server role.  My server is running the Mailbox role, as well as the Hub Transport and Client Access roles.

How do I get this service to show up in the list, so that I can start it up?

Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that you have the Hub and Mailbox roles on the same server.  Is your Hub available?  How does the event viewer look?  Do you see any back pressure warnings?

Comment: Yes, this server has both the Hub Transport and Mailbox roles.

I don't see any back pressure warnings, however; my research indicates that those warnings come from the MSExchangeMailSubmission service.

And that is the crux of my problem; it's not running, and it's not listed in Services, so I can't start it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with good old "setup.com /mode:recoverserver" to force a reinstallation of all the Exchange binaries.